# Seaborn barplot legend labels lose color

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn boxplot which when I try to use plt.legend("Strings") to change name of labels it loses the colors of the labels. I need to change labels while maintaining the color coding, but I do not know how to do this after searching for an answer.

The Hues legend 1-4 corresponds from 1 = Very interested in politics to 4 = not at all interested. I want to change the legend hue labels from 1-4 to how interested they are in politics.

My code is:

## Packages

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## I didnt know how to create dataframe in any simpler way so i did this

```
a1 = {'Reads Newspapers': 0, 'Interest in Politics': 1}
a2 = {'Reads Newspapers': 0, 'Interest in Politics': 2}
a3 = {'Reads Newspapers': 0, 'Interest in Politics': 3}
a4 = {'Reads Newspapers': 0, 'Interest in Politics': 4}
b1 = {'Reads Newspapers': 1, 'Interest in Politics': 1}
b2 = {'Reads Newspapers': 1, 'Interest in Politics': 2}
b3 = {'Reads Newspapers': 1, 'Interest in Politics': 3}
b4 = {'Reads Newspapers': 1, 'Interest in Politics': 4}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=a1, index=range(1))
df1 = pd.concat([df1]*23)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=a2, index=range(1))
df2 = pd.concat([df2]*98)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=a3, index=range(1))
df3 = pd.concat([df3]*99)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data=a4, index=range(1))
df4 = pd.concat([df4]*18)
b1 = pd.DataFrame(data=b1, index=range(1))
b1 = pd.concat([b1]*468)
b2 = pd.DataFrame(data=b2, index=range(1))
b2 = pd.concat([b2]*899)
b3 = pd.DataFrame(data=b3, index=range(1))
b3 = pd.concat([b3]*413)
b4 = pd.DataFrame(data=b4, index=range(1))
b4 = pd.concat([b4]*46)
data = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,b1,b2,b3,b4])
```

## Actual plotting that produces error

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
g = sns.barplot(data=data, x='Reads Newspapers', estimator=len,y='Interest in Politics', hue='Interest in Politics' )
plt.ylabel("Sample Size")
ax = plt.subplot()
ax = ax.set_xticklabels(["No","Yes"])

#plt.legend(["very interested","somewhat interested", "only a little interested", "not at all interested "],)
#plt.savefig('Newspaper policy')
```

[image: Seaborn Boxplot about interest in politics]

I tried using `plt.legend` but the legend labels lose their color when I do this so it becomes strings with no color association, making it even worse than before.

I have now editted in the entirety of my script.

https://github.com/HenrikMorpheus/Newspaper-reading-survey/blob/master/politicalinterest.ipynb
It loads with an error for some reason i dont know, but you should be able to open the notebook in jupyter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Use dedicated dataframe column

An option is to create a new column in the dataframe with the respective labels in, and use this column as input for the `hue`, such that the desired labels are automatically created.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"reads" : ["Yes"] * 250 + ["No"]*150,
                  "interest" : [4,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1]*40})

labels=["very interested","somewhat interested", 
        "only a little interested", "not at all interested"]
# Create new dataframe column with the labels instead of numbers
df["Interested in politics"] = df["interest"].map(dict(zip(range(1,5), labels)))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
# Use newly created dataframe column as hue
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='reads', estimator=len,y='interest', 
                 hue='Interested in politics', hue_order=labels)
ax.set_ylabel("Sample Size")

plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Setting the labels manually.

You may obtain the handles and labels for the legend via `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` and use them to create a new legend with the labels from the list.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"reads" : ["Yes"] * 250 + ["No"]*150,
                  "interest" : [4,2,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,1]*40})

labels=["very interested","somewhat interested", 
        "only a little interested", "not at all interested"]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='reads', estimator=len,y='interest', hue='interest' )
ax.set_ylabel("Sample Size")

h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h, labels, title="Interested in politics")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your help, i really appreciate that you took the time.

Seaborn has so much usability but also makes some things, such as this surprisingly hard.

I ended up using the second solution you posted. ax.get_legend_handles_labels().
Have a good day