# how to manually assign color to type of categorical variable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am creating 2 plots in below code. I have categories values in the `JobDomain` column as

- Cat1
- Cat2
- Cat3

The code below is generating 2 plots each with different colors for above categories. I need to keep both the plots to have same color for these 3 categories.

```
colors = ["#F28E2B", "#4E79A7","#79706E"]

edu = (df.groupby(['JobDomain'])['sal']
                         .value_counts(normalize=True)
                         .rename('Percentage')
                         .mul(100)
                         .reset_index()
                         .sort_values('sal'))

coding = (df.groupby(['JobDomain'])['sal2']
                         .value_counts(normalize=True)
                         .rename('Percentage')
                         .mul(100)
                         .reset_index()
                         .sort_values('sal2'))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(20, 6),sharey=True)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4)

p=sns.barplot(x="sal",y="Percentage",hue="JobDomain",data=edu,
              ax=axs[0],palette=sns.color_palette(colors))
q=sns.barplot(x="sal2",y="Percentage",hue="JobDomain",data=coding,
              ax=axs[1],palette=sns.color_palette(colors))
```

Comment: Maybe you can leave out `.sort_values('sal')` and `.sort_values('sal2')` ? That way the jobdomains would have the same order in both graphs.

Answer (score 6):

By creating a dictionary mapping each cathegory to a color (and passing it to `palette` without calling `sns.color_palette`). An example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
from pandas import DataFrame
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = DataFrame({'JobDomain': ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat1', 'Cat3'],
                'sal':       [  110,     90,    100,    200,    130],
                'sal2':      [  100,    280,    320,    240,    440]
                })

colors = {'Cat1': "#F28E2B", 'Cat2': "#4E79A7", 'Cat3': "#79706E"}

edu = (df.groupby(['JobDomain'])['sal']
                         .value_counts(normalize=True)
                         .rename('Percentage')
                         .mul(100)
                         .reset_index()
                         .sort_values('sal'))
coding = (df.groupby(['JobDomain'])['sal2']
                         .value_counts(normalize=True)
                         .rename('Percentage')
                         .mul(100)
                         .reset_index()
                         .sort_values('sal2'))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(20, 6),sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4)
p = sns.barplot(x="sal",y="Percentage",hue="JobDomain",data=edu,ax=axs[0],palette=colors)
q = sns.barplot(x="sal2",y="Percentage",hue="JobDomain",data=coding,ax=axs[1],palette=colors)

h, l = p.get_legend_handles_labels()
l, h = zip(*sorted(zip(l, h)))
p.legend(h, l, title="Job Domain")
q.legend(h, l, title="Job Domain")

plt.show()
```

PS: to sort the legends again, insert just before `plt.show()`:

```py
h, l = p.get_legend_handles_labels()
l, h = zip(*sorted(zip(l, h)))
p.legend(h, l, title="Job Domain")
q.legend(h, l, title="Job Domain")
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Thank you :) ... one more question, how can we order the color legend to show Cat1, Cat2 and Cat3 in order?

Comment: Maybe just leave out the `.sort_values('sal2')` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734332/seaborn-barplot-legend-labels-lose-color contains some tricks to manipulate the legend

Comment: yes, but it changes the bars placement in the plot as well. any option available to make this manual change only within the color legion box?

Comment: Thank you. ill check this post.